# Output into variable within a batch file

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I've copied some files and want to count the files for an output message.

There are examples involving using a file, "%$set%" and for %ii%. I don't like the "file" solution and can't get the others to work.

```
SET COUNT=<dir /a-d /s /b %TO% | find /c ":"
echo %COUNT% of 10 files copied
```

I'm aiming to get "10 of 10 files copied", what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Got it! The "For" example was erroring with "| was unexpected at this time."
escaping with "^" has done the trick.

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /a-d /s /b %TO% ^| find /c ":"') do set COUNT=%%i
echo %COUNT% of 10 files copied
```

10 of 10 files copied

see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120731-00/?p=7003